# Compute Gamma(x+1/2)/Gamma(x)

Tags: python, math, scipy

I need to compute Gamma(x+1/2)/Gamma(x) for reasonably large x.  If I just use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gamma.html it fails as the denominator and numerator are huge. However the fraction itself is around sqrt(x).  How can I compute this fraction accurately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `beta(a, b) = gamma(a) * gamma(b) / gamma(a+b)`

```
from scipy.special import gamma, beta
x = 10
print gamma(x+0.5)/gamma(x)
print gamma(0.5)/beta(x, 0.5)
```